# Routes и Router - как правильно настроить (Vue.js/Node.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, express, vue-router

У меня на фронте используется Vue. Там я настроил vue-router, чтоб по конкретным запросам отдавать соответствующие страницы. На бэке я использую node/express. Вопрос в следующем: когда я в адресной строке пишу полный путь к какому-либо компоненту, то он отдает страницу и все ок, но если я укажу там URL, который я использую в качестве endpoint в каком-либо из get-запросов своего api, например `router.get('/users', (req, res) => {res.send(users)})`, то он отдает JSON со всеми юзерами с базы данных. Но ведь это ненормально, там email, имена и т.д. Пароль конечно хеширован, но тем не менее. Как этого избежать?
Кусок моего app.js в node:

```
const routes = require("./routes");
app.use("/", routes);

app.use(history({ verbose: true, index: '/' }));
app.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  if(checkRoutes(req.originalUrl)) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html');
  }
});
```

Тут checkRoutes(url) проверяет наличие такого маршрута в vue-router.

Comment: Используйте авторизацию для проверки, добавьте права доступа. Как самое простое решение, можно вместо get использовать post запросы, а для get выдавать ошибку.

Comment: А как я получу необходимые данные с помощью POST запроса?

Answer (score 0):

`app.post("/users", callback)` на сервере, запрос post на клиенте. Но вообще советую настроить авторизациюю

Comment: Так вроде авторизация настроена. Но как ее привязать к запросам к api напрямую в браузере?

Comment: Если Вы используете для проверки авторизации токен, то стоит проверять именно его, если используете сессии, то sessionID, или ещё что то. И без него отправлять ошибку

Comment: Возвращаясь у хешированному паролю. По идее, его и не нужно передавать. Если же нужно его как то менять, то использовать для этого отдельные методы. И не в коем случае не передавать его куда то ещё, только сравнение на сервере.

Comment: Допустим, я авторизовался. Зашел в админ-панель и работаю там. Кликаю по кнопке, чтоб увидеть юзеров/документы и т.п. При это отправляется гет-запрос на сервер. Вместе с гет-запросом отправлять токен? Как query, например?

Comment: Если Вы внимательно посмотрите заголовки того, что отправляется в запросе, то увидите, что там много дополнительной информации.  Если все настроено хорошо, то там же будет ее предаваться информация об авторизации, и эту информацию можно проверять на сервере. Если же она там не передаются, то получается, что любой человек, который знает end point Вашего приложения может получить информацию из БД когда угодно, даже без авторизации.

Comment: Информация об авторизации, т.е. токен или что то ещё как правило передается в заголовках и при этом добавляется автоматически. В axios, например, это реализовано через использование базовых инстасов. И ответ сервера идёт только после проверки этой информации.

Comment: Спасибо. Уже довольно поздно/ или ещё довольно но рано. Утром попробую ещё раз "приглядеться" в заголовки запроса. Вы не против, если я с вами свяжусь как-нибудь по-другому, если что? В vk, например?

Comment: Пожалуйста. Пишите на idushii-mail@ya.ru, я увижу.

Comment: Благодарю. Напишу